# Were there common Latin stutter words?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, modern-life

In English, we say often say 'um' when we're trying to think about the next word to say. In Japanese it's 'anno.' Is there a known phrase like this in Latin?

Comment: It's entirely up to you whether the question linked to by @Adam answers your question. You can edit the question to add a link your question to what was there, or you can say it's a duplicate. Although duplicate questions are technically closed, there's nothing wrong with them.

Comment: This is an excellent answer to my question. Thank you Adam!